# What do the horse's messages mean?

Tags: torchlight

I get a cryptic message every time I click on the horse. Example:

[image]

Other messages include

- Gazing into the horse's eyes, you feel on the verge of understanding
  a deep mystery.
- You ponder the horse's speed, and are inspired to
  quicken your own step.
- The horse's calm in the face of danger steels your will.
- The horse gazes upon you calmly, reminding you that patience is a virtue.
- Peering deep into the horse's eyes, you feel you are not yet ready for its wisdom.
- The horse fixes you with a withering gaze.

These sound a lot like the stat increase messages in ADOM, because they reference things like speed and willpower; however, my stats don't seem to be increasing on their own, and I get the feeling that the game might be just messing with me...

Comment: https://twitter.com/Horse_ebooks

Comment: Ahhh, Torchlight 2, full of easter eggs...

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz What the hell have I just read.

Comment: Short answer: the game is messing with you.  The horse itself does nothing but cycle through a long list of messages.  You should take the warnings about the power and might of the horses seriously if you ever intend to enter the secret horse level though - the horses there are hostile and not to be underestimated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, the Horse's only purpose is to hint at the "Secret Horse Level", much how Diablo had a cow that could be clicked (though the Secret Cow Level only existed in the sequel).

To clarify, the cows in Diablo also responded when clicked on:

- "Yup, that's a cow all right!"
- "I am not thirsty"
- "Hey! I am no milkmaid!"